# Google Spreadsheet: Use column + n in formular

Tags: google-sheets, calculated-columns

In my spreadsheet in Column X I have the following formular:

```
=ImportRange('_keys'!$B$2;"2015!A200:A203")
```

Now I'd like to copy this formular to column X+n (in this case X+2) so that it should look like:

```
=ImportRange('_keys'!$B$2;"2015!C200:C203")
```

But it doesn't change the column and I have to change it by hand. 
Is it possible to change this formular that it always uses the column where the formular is in?

Comment: I don't think you can because you have to pass in the range as a range_string, wrapping it in quotation marks. Because of that the cells won't change retroactively.

Comment: Finaly I got it working. See my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

I wrote a simple custom function that converts numbers into letters.

```
   /**
   * Converts number of column into column letter
   *
   * @param {Number} aNumer Number of column
   * @return {String} Letter of column
   * @customfunction
   */
    function COL_NR2LETTER(aNumber) {
      var letterArray = ['-', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AP', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AV', 'AW', 'AX', 'AY', 'AZ'];
      if (aNumber < 1 || aNumber > letterArray.length) 
         throw "column index out of bound error";

      return letterArray [aNumber];  
    }
```

Now its possible to copy

```
=ImportRange('_keys'!$B$2;
   "2015!" & COL_NR2LETTER(Column(A1)) &"200:"& COL_NR2LETTER(Column(A1)) &"203")
```

from Column X into a column X+n.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `COLUMN()` function to get the column of the current cell as a number.  Using `ADDRESS()` you can turn it into a cell reference string.  See the docs for [COLUMN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373) and [ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308).

Your code becomes

```
=ImportRange('_keys'!$B$2;
             CONCATENATE("2015!", ADDRESS(200, COLUMN()-Y, 4),
                         ":",     ADDRESS(203, COLUMN()-Y, 4))
            )
```

where Y is the offset between column A and column X (where this formula is located).  The third argument of `ADDRESS` makes both the row and column relative (without the `$`).  Note that the order of arguments to `ADDRESS` is `row` then `column`, annoyingly.